# How do I preserve this variable through multiple function calls?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
$k = 0;
    //loop through every question present in query results and run function to present the different question structures
    while ($qs = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_questions))
    {
        $type = $qs['item_type'];
        $item_id = $qs['item_id'];
        $question = $qs['question_text'];
        $question_2 = $qs['question_text_2'];
        present_question($item_id, $type, $question, $question_2, $i, $k);
        $i ++;
        $ids[] = $item_id;
    }
```

now skipping out the switch case in the middle it can end up at this function:

```
function multi_response($data, $ID, $k){
    $j = 1;     
    while ($answers = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
        {       
            $as = $answers['text_value'];
            echo "<input name='multi_response[$k][id]' type='hidden' value='$ID'>";
            echo "<strong>".$j.  ".</strong><input type='checkbox' name='multi_response[$k][answer]' value='$as'> $as</br>";
            $k++;
            $j++;
        }       
    return;
}
```

What I want to do is essentially everytime `multi_response()` is called, `$k` is to continuing from where it was last instead of from 0. `$k` is basically my index value and if it resets to 0 it is overwriting the previous data in the array `multi_response[][]`

I have been trying to return `$k` to the original loop and parse it back through with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Send $k by reference:

```
function multi_response($data, $ID, &$k){
   //rest of function here ...
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

@Emil was just typing that out :)

Comment: You can read about references in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php